# How can i solve a memory error of python scikit image function color.rgb2gray()?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm working in python with many images.
While I'm analyzing this [image]

when I use:

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wamp\www\NewIESP\FUNZIONApy\up1feature.py", line 180, in <module>
    updatefeatures(infile)
  File "C:\wamp\www\NewIESP\FUNZIONApy\up1feature.py", line 43, in updatefeatures
    temp = compareup1features.comparison(path)
  File "C:\wamp\www\NewIESP\FUNZIONApy\compareup1features.py", line 496, in comparison
    skellist = moduloSkeleton.skelfeatures(path1img)
  File "C:\wamp\www\NewIESP\FUNZIONApy\moduloSkeleton.py", line 1418, in skelfeatures
    img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 661, in rgb2gray
    return _convert(gray_from_rgb, rgb[:, :, :3])[..., 0]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 462, in _convert
    return np.ascontiguousarray(out)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 409, in ascontiguousarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
MemoryError
```

How can I solve this memory error?
If it is not possible, how can I say to "recognize" this kind of image and skip it!?

Comment: Are you sure the errors are caused by the above lines of code and not by what follows after them? The above code works fine for me. Also, just to be sure, you might want to check if the image is read in properly.

Comment: the next line is: p2 = numpy.percentile(img, 2) but if i delete this line i have always that error and only with this kind of image!

Comment: I tried also in the shell and i get the same error.

Comment: I think it is the file size, if i skip the images with a >>2MB size i can run my script

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: The files are big 4 or 5 MB

Comment: It is a matter of that i worked with others 80 files? Because i tried also without this kind of image and after 89 files analyzed python crashes. How can i handle this?

Comment: Do you happen to keep a reference to ALL 89 files in memory? If that is the case then you are using up to (sum of all images + overhead) amount of memory. Note that after an image is read into memory it gets decompressed. This means it is usually a lot bigger than the 4 to 5 Mb it takes up on disk. It may be the case that you just ran out of memory and the problem is not with the image or with the code. To debug, just run this code on JUST the image when the crash occurred. If it is able to run, then the problem is not with code or image.

Comment: I checked another time only with this image and now it crashes at this line: imgbnbin = mh.morph.dilate(gray, disk7) a mahotas function

Comment: Do you mind posting more of your code? The ones before and after what you shown above. Don't you find it odd that the code "works" for the other images but not for this one? My previous experience with this when code breaks for only one or a few cases is when there is something wrong with those files that violate some implicit assumptions you made in your code e.g., file naming convention, image formats etc. Without seeing the context surrounding your code, it is hard to give advice.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434258/why-python-raise-a-runtime-error-only-with-certain-images i make a new question with much more information. The thinks are a little bit change!

Comment: This image is so big and that might cause the error. Also as I remember skimage imread converts data into float. Therefore it allocates more memory than a normal img format that is uint8. Try resizing img first or try convert it yo uint8 first.

Comment: @erogol, resizing doesn't always work, e.g. currently measure.label from skiimage can break.